# Datadog SQL ERROR: there is no parameter $1 - AWS Aurora Postgres v12

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameters, amazon-aurora, datadog

Some Postgres SQL statements like below is causing several errors:

```
SELECT 
    datadog.explain_statement($stmt$SELECT n.nspname = ANY(current_schemas(true)), n.nspname, t.typname 
FROM 
    pg_catalog.pg_type t 
JOIN 
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON t.typnamespace = n.oid 
WHERE 
    t.oid = $1$stmt$)
```

User: datadog

Datadog's support ask me to update the agent to the latest version 7.32.0 and the number of errors got reduced but still not fixed. So, they asked to set `prepared_statements: false` in the file `config/database.yml` from my core api but, it cannot be done according to DevOps because our application needs it enabled.

So, we tried to set `prepared_statements: false` in the **datadog agent** config file only: `releases/datadog.yaml`, but there is no such configuration according to [datadog docs](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/master/postgres/datadog_checks/postgres/data/conf.yaml.example)

Does anyone know how to fix it or disable it on the datadog side only and avoid impacting our application, please?

*CI/CD code in Rails and Python*

*AWS Postgres Aurora v12*

Comment: datadog-agent 7.34, same error